# Host RESTHeart on IBM WebSphere

Tags: mongodb, jboss, websphere, undertow, restheart

I want to host/run [RESTHeart](http://restheart.org) on an IBM WebSphere Application Server (traditional V8.5 or Liberty). For default RESTHeart is made to run on Undertow/JBoss(?).

Is there any possibility to do so? I couldn't find anything about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. RESTHeart is a plain Java application, it is NOT meant to be ran inside any application server. It's not true it's made to run inside Undertow/JBoss, instead RESTHeart **embeds Undertow**, to serve HTTP requests very efficiently.

RESTHeart has been developed with a micro-services architecture in mind, because we wanted something simple, without the need to run and manage a fully fledged application server in our production environments.